# How do I resolve unknown error?

Tags: fatal-error

I was editing config > web settings trying to fix an error that only happens in safari, and my fiddling, lack of experience/knowledge, trial and error approach all lead to the white screen of death both back and frontend.

How do I resolve this? Im unable to get the error report to show by editing the # out of the appropriate line in index.php but nothing.

I guess my two questions are - how do I find the correct settings for web area in config? pic attached of current settings.
and failing being able to fix this myself how do I find someone who is an expert and I can pay to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I have cleared the cache and sessions

Comment: Is it a secure only site? Have you checked your logs?

Comment: no its not a secure only site. By checking Logs do I simple open up var/logs/system.log?  --- that contains this 2015-01-15T22:07:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 2 for Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addItem()  in /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php on line 46773
2015-01-15T22:07:18+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: name  in /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php on line 46778
2015-01-15T22:07:18+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: name  in /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php on line 46780

Comment: Yes, Id also check your apache or equivalent logs as well for when the issue occurs. Blank pages are a failure to load and *should* indicate what the problem is.

Comment: Any Idea what this means "Premature end of script headers: php-script" ? Thats from apache error log